# PHP variable to Xcode variable

Tags: php, iphone, xcode

how can i get an integer variable from PHP page and save it to the integer variable in my program...

USInteger *number =  an integer variable from PHP page...

Comment: uhm... huh? you have to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about IPC I think ... InterProcess Communication ... The PHP "page" is itself a program ... you'll need to setup a way to communicate with your "program" on both the "page" side and the "program" side ... one option of course is to output the variable in the "page" and parse it through the "program"

Of course IPC is more commonly related to pipes, sockets, and shared memory.

Of course this is assuming you are actually attempting to get the value of a variable in a PHP page and assign it to the value of the variable in your "program" ... Its very possible I'm wrong in that understanding of your question.

Comment: you have no idea what the op is actually asking, yet you throw around buzzwords...

Comment: hop: considering the question is nonsensical, I consider this answer to be suitable.